# jquery click send function wont work only update the same field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a click send function for my emoticon function but it is not working correctly.

I have created this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/ucscwew1/3/) from jsfiddle. In this demo you can se there are four textarea and smiley. When you click smiley then other alert (comments will be come here) changing to (Plese write your comment). What is the problem on there and what is the solution anyone can help me in this regard ?

JS

```
$('.sendcomment').bind('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var ID = $(this).attr("data-msgid");
        var comment = $(this).val();

        if ($.trim(comment).length == 0) {
            $("#commentload" + ID).text("Plese write your comment!");
        } else {
            $("#commentload" + ID).text(comment);
            $("#commentid" + ID).val('').css("height", "35px").focus();
        }
    }
});
/**/
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on("click", '.emo', function () {

        var ID = $(this).attr("data-msgid");
        var comment = $(this).val();

        if ($.trim(comment).length == 0) {
            $("#commentload" + ID).text("nothing!");
        } else {
            $("#commentload" + ID).text(comment);
            $("#commentid" + ID).val('').css("height", "35px").focus();
        }

    });
});
$('body').on('click', '.sm-sticker', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var theComment = $(this).parents('.container').find('.sendcomment');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var sticker = $(this).attr('sticker');
    var msg = jQuery.trim(theComment.val());

    if (msg == '') {
        var sp = '';
    } else {
        var sp = ' ';
    }

    theComment.val(jQuery.trim(msg + sp + sticker + sp));
    var e = $.Event("keydown");
    e.keyCode = 13; // # Some key code value
    $('.sendcomment').trigger(e);
});
```

HTML

Comment: I think you mean Clicking on one smiley should only update the same field and not others?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal Yes you understand it correctly.

Comment: Please add `event.stopPropagation();` in all your eventListeners since you are binding the events on body they are propagating from the element upwards to the body element.
That I think will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 43 line `$('.sendcomment').trigger(e);` you trigger keydown event to all textareas. Change it to `theComment.trigger(e)`